# PHP htmlspecialchars() function error when trying to use UTF-8 string

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, htmlspecialchars, navicat

I did the following things:

1. I have a spreadsheet with data. One of the rows has a ü character in it.
2. I save this as a CSV file in OpenOffice.org. When it asks me for a character encoding, I choose UTF-8.
3. I use Navicat to create a MySQL database table, InnoDB with UTF-8 utf8_general encoding and import the CSV.
4. I try to use PHP function `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` where `$string` is the string containing the special ü character.

It gives me an error: **Invalid multibyte sequence in argument**. When I change `'UTF-8'` with `'ISO8859-1'`, no error is thrown, but the incorrect character is shown. (The 'unknown character' character, looks like `<?>`)

If I use an HTML form to update the string in the database, the error disappears and the character is displayed correctly, however, when I then look at the record in Navicat, it looks two characters:

`[1/4][A with some thing on top of it]`

Some multibyte that isn't seen as one character.`

What is going on, where are things going wrong, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't understand where the "invalid multibyte" error comes from, I'm pretty sure `htmlspecialchars()` is [not your culprit](http://en.php.net/htmlspecialchars):

> For the purposes of this function, the charsets ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8, cp866, cp1251, cp1252, and KOI8-R are effectively equivalent, as the characters affected by htmlspecialchars() occupy the same positions in all of these charsets.

In my understanding, `htmlspecialchars()` should work fine for a UTF-8 string without specifying a character set. My bet would be that either the HTML page containing the form, or the database connection you use is not UTF-8 encoded. For the latter, try sending a

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

to mySQL before doing the insert.

Comment: According to the mysql general query log, `SET NAMES utf8` is actually sent to the MySQL server. Although there is no form in this process (there is one when I update the record), that is set to UTF-8 using an HTML meta tag. (But again, the error already pops in before the form was used.)

Comment: @Pelle can you confirm it is actually sent to the server *for that connection*?  And to confirm, the error you quote is actually thrown by `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Figured it out. All stuff was UTF-8, EXCEPT: the connection when used to SELECT the data. Putting SET NAMES UTF8 before the select statements fixed it.

Comment: Note, SET NAMES is only needed once per connection, right after connecting.